# Finding Quarter of the year for current day and next four quarter

Tags: php, datetime

How to construct an array having elements current Quarter as first element and next four quarters as next elements.

Consider for the year 27-Nov-13,
array should contain elements as follows

```
$ac_quarters = array (AC4-13,AC1-14,AC2-14,AC3-14,AC4-14);
```

Please see me as novice to PHP programming. 
Currently I have written code as shown below. Surely there gotta be better logic than this.

```
$date = "2013-1-13"; 
$d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $date); 

if ($d["month"]==1 || $d["month"]==2 || $d["month"]==3) {
    $ac_quarters = array (AC1-13,AC2-13,AC3-13,AC4-13,AC1-14);

}
```

Comment: Even novices can try *something* before asking for help. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Checkout date() on the php manual

Comment: @JohnConde, Please see the edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid special casing each month and looking it up, find out which quarter you're currently in by dividing the month number by 3, and then iterating through four quarters ahead.

```
$current = floor((date('n') - 1) / 3);

$year = date('y');
$quarters = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $q = (($current+$i)%4) + 1;
    $quarters[] = "AC" . $q . "-" . $year;

    if (($current+$i+1)%4 == 0)
    {
        $year++;
    }
}

var_dump($quarters);
```

We increment $year if the next quarter would be the start of a new year (which will give us 0 when using the modulo operator). You can use strtotime() if you want to change the startdate in the date() calls at the top.

Comment: @xcy7e웃 How did you input "25.03.2016" into the example above? It just iterates from today's date, and outputs the current + next quarters. There's nothing that parses a date to output something. If you're talking about the `strtotime` line, remember that you have to add it to *both* date calls, not just the first.

Comment: I added the date-string to both "date"-Functions as 2nd param into a strtotime().

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. You'll have to subtract a month, since we're dividing by three to get the current - and that will give the wrong output when starting from a month dividable by three. I've updated the answer, thanks for spotting the bug!